Creating an ssh keypair for AWS Lightsail/EC2 instances doesn't work as expected
I've created a fair few SSH keypairs in my days but AWS seems to handle them differently. I'm using AWS Lightsail and it has a notion of 'default' keypairs. This is fine for the 'normal' user that AWS has set up for me. In the case of my Lightsail Ubuntu server, this user is called 'ubuntu'.
I have created another standard user account on this server, let's call this account 'fred'. Normally, I'd log in as fred on my remote host, run ssh-keygen and create the public/private keys. I'd copy the private key back to my local machine, set the correct perms and then do something like ssh -i privatekeyforfred.pem fred@remotemachine.xyz
If I try this tact with my lightsail/EC2 instance I get: Permission denied (publickey).
If I follow AWS's terribly written guides on the matter, they tell me to do all sorts of stuff in their dashboard and create a 'custom' key: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lightsail/latest/userguide/amazon-lightsail-ssh-using-terminal.html
This custom key seems to have no notion of the identity (fred) for whom I need to log into the remote host for, so I have no idea how that could ever work. Regardless, I thought I'd give it a spin, alas, my concerns were indeed accurate.
I have googled for hours, and I am at my end! This should be a simple thing, why has AWS made this such a strangely difficult task to accomplish, and can anyone throw an old Unix dog a hand here?
Cheers!

What keeps you from adding the key manually to the .authorized_keys file on the server?

I'd log in as fred on my remote host, run ssh-keygen and create the public/private keys - unrelated, but you should change that behaviour. The private key should be created on your local machine and never leave it. You should copy the public key to the server, not the private key from it.


Normally, I'd log in as fred on my remote host, run ssh-keygen and create the public/private keys. I'd copy the private key back to my local machine, set the correct perms and then do something like

That's a little backwards. Although it makes absolutely no difference to SSH as to where the key is generated, the recommended process is to generate the keypair directly on the machine that it'll be used from, just so that you wouldn't need to transfer the private key file over the network at all. So you should generate the keypair locally, then transfer the public key to the right place at your server.

This custom key seems to have no notion of the identity (fred) for whom I need to log into the remote host for, so I have no idea how that could ever work.

Standard SSH keys have no notion of user identity in the first place.
(The piece of text at the end of your public key is not that; it's a comment field that has no meaning to the client nor to the server. Its purpose is so that you could distinguish between multiple keys on the same server.)
It all works because the opposite lookup is done instead – the SSH client always transmits the username separately, so the SSH server can check whether the "authorized keys" list for that specific username contains the key.
On Unix servers running OpenSSH, that list is kept in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys of whichever user you're trying to log in to (unless the path has been changed in /etc/ssh/sshd_config to something else). You didn't mention adding anything to this file as part of your key generation process, but without that, the new key isn't going to work – it does not happen automatically after ssh-keygen.
Most cloud providers have a "first-boot setup" process that pre-creates this file for the default 'ubuntu' user; the "custom key" settings at Lightsail would therefore only have an effect for VMs created after that point (and still only for the default user), but they will have no effect on already running VMs.
(All of this is another reason why your current process is a little bit backwards – if you're accessing the same server from five PCs, and they all use keys generated on the server, then all of the keys will have the exact same comment field by default. Normally, when you have a list of client hosts in 'authorized_keys' at the server, you would want to see the client descriptions there.)

can anyone throw an old Unix dog a hand here?

Check your server's log files. Set your sshd to LogLevel DEBUG and it will tell you why it's rejecting the key – although most likely that's because it cannot find the key in your ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.
It can also be that sshd doesn't like the permissions of that file being too open, or that it's owned by the wrong account, or that sshd_config was set up to use a different path; either way, there will be a message in the system logs.

Thanks for your help so far: This is what I get in the logs upon using ssh-copy-id:Apr 12 02:35:38 ip-172-26-3-84 sshd[83750]: AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/share/ec2-instance-connect/eic_run_authorized_keys  SHA256:vZw8hEnsVLyiVEyoqO3P3RkHH8VC55rKRPoXKUfvmfY failed, status 22 Apr 12 02:35:38 ip-172-26-3-84 sshd[83750]: Connection closed by authenticating user  161.29.23.47 port 1218 [preauth]. The perms on the keys are valid AFAIK.

Well well, I've figured the answer out and it was a lot more complex than I'd have thought imagined, thanks to our friends at AWS ;)
For anyone seeking the answer, here's what you have to do:
NB I am assuming you have already created the user fred on the lightsail instance with 'adduser' or similar, and it already has a ~/.ssh directory with the appropriate the user permissions. I have also outlined which host you have to be on for each step [desktop] is your own computer, [lightsail] for the AWS lightsail (or EC2 instance).
Step 1: Create SSH Key Pair (if not already created)
[desktop]
Open your terminal.
Generate a new SSH key pair (or use an existing one). To generate a new key, execute something like:
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -f ~/.ssh/fred_lightsail

NB: When prompted for a passphrase, you can choose to leave it empty for password-less logins.
Ensure your private key (fred_lightsail) is secure:
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/fred_lightsail

Step 2: Upload Public Key to AWS Lightsail
[desktop]
Next, the magic-aws-sauce! You need to upload the public key (fred_lightsail.pub) to your Lightsail instance. You have to do this via the AWS Lightsail console.

Go to the Lightsail Management Console (https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com) / or navigate to the Lightsail section from main AWS Management console.
Ensure SSH is enabled in firewall: Click on your instance, then go to the Networking tab. Under Firewall, make sure that SSH (port 22) is allowed.
Add SSH key: Go to the Account page from the Lightsail home, and under SSH keys, upload your public key (fred_lightsail.pub).

Step 3: Set up User and Permissions on Lightsail
[lightsail]
SSH into your Lightsail instance using the default 'ubuntu' user.
ssh -i /path/to/default/ubuntu-key ubuntu@your-instance-ip

Add the public key to the new user's authorized keys:
echo "your-public-key-contents" | sudo tee /home/fred/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo chmod 600 /home/fred/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo chown -R fred:fred /home/fred/.ssh

(you could alternatively scp/sftp the pubkey to your ubuntu user and just mv the file into /home/fred and change the perms)
Step 4: Log in and enjoy!
[desktop]
Now on your desktop, you should be able to SSH into your Lightsail instance as 'fred' using:
ssh -i ~/.ssh/fred_lightsail fred@your-instance-ip

I hope that this helps what are surely loads of frustrated 'normal' Linux users out there. The AWS documentation on this step is inaccurate at best!
